# USB Type B: Why male vs. female differentiation is not enough?

Tags: usb, cable, hosts

This [manufacturer website](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/0E543C70602423C486256DB8006208DE) is very definite:

> The two types of plugs have the same number of pins, and are
>   electrically identical. They are only different mechanically. This was
>   an intentional feature designed by the USB Implementers Forum to
>   prevent connecting a host to another host, which could cause a short
>   circuit.

Why male vs. female differentiation is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because

1. sockets for female plugs are bulky compared to male, requiring your phone etc to be twice as thick as it currently is.
2. there would be nothing preventing you from chaining USB cables, which isn't supported without a repeater.

Comment: But the cables as they are designed (males at both ends) imply female phone sockets! Do you mean the USB design favours bulky phones? I do not also understand how bulkness is related to the need to introduce a new type.

Comment: the plugs are male, the sockets are 'for male plugs' - perhaps I didn't explain clearly enough. Sockets for female plugs are larger. I've edited.

Comment: to try explain it without it turning into some bizarre 'birds & bees' lesson... The small male plug fits nicely in the larger female socket. to encompass that female socket as a plug, you would then have to 'box' it & the space needed for the male plug inside a still larger enclosure.